# pandas qcut and pandas cut functions do not distribute the number of items uniformly

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `pandas.qcut` and `pandas.cut` to distribute the number of items uniformly across deciles based on a probability calculated. However, the items do not get distributed uniformly across deciles in both cases. Below is my code in each case:

```
pd.qcut(df['prob'], q=10, labels=False, duplicates='drop')
pd.cut (df['prob'], bins=10, labels=False)
```

Below is what I get in each case:

```
for pd.qcut:
Decile  Count of Items
 0        20300
 1        7000
 2        13800
 3        14000
 4        13000
 5        13800
 6        13700
 7        14600
 8        19000
 9        70000

for pd.cut:
Decile  Count of Items
 0       1700
 1       19000
 2       39000
 3       39000
 4       32000
 5       3100
 6       3000
 7       100
 8       20
 9       25
```

I didn't put the exact numbers but the magnitude should give an idea. the probability ranges from 0.01 to 0.15.
How can I distribute the items evenly across deciles?